# Out of gas only when transferring ICX token

Tags: transactions, gas, myetherwallet

I get the following error

```
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]
```

ONLY with `$ICX` token, it works fine with all other tokens I am transferring. Is this even possible and how do I troubleshot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was strangely enough (at least for me) - there was indeed just *not enough Gas*. Whereas it was always enough to set like 30-40k with other ERC-20 tokens, with `ICX` I was finally successful to transfer after setting Gas limit to 100k.